# How to show download progress in another class?

Tags: qt, qt5

How I can show download progress from file downloaded in Options window on `DownloadProgress` window?

**Options.h:**

```
class Options : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QScopedPointer<QNetworkAccessManager> nam;
public:
    explicit Options(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Options();

QNetworkReply *red;
    private slots:
    void writeData();
    void downloadFinished();


private:
    Ui::Options *ui;

public:

    QString getResolution(int width, int height);
};
```

**Options.cpp**

(...)

```
void Options::on_toggleGDownload_clicked()
{

QString rep;

// shows download progress
DownloadProgress n;
n.exec();

QFile dwnl("somepath");
dwnl.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
red = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("someurl")));
connect(red, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(writeData()));
connect(red, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(updateDownloadProgress(qint64, qint64)));


}
```

(...)

**DownloadProgress.h:**

```
class DownloadProgress;
}

class DownloadProgress : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
   explicit DownloadProgress(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~DownloadProgress();

public slots:
    void updateDownloadProgress(qint64, qint64);

private:
    Ui::DownloadProgress *ui;
};
```

**DownloadProgress.cpp:**

(...)

```
DownloadProgress::DownloadProgress(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::DownloadProgress)
{
 ui->setupUi(this);

}

DownloadProgress::~DownloadProgress()
{
delete ui;
}

void DownloadProgress::updateDownloadProgress(qint64 readBytes, qint64 totalBytes)
{
ui->progressBar->setMaximum(totalBytes);
ui->progressBar->setValue(readBytes);

}
```

I'm very new to Qt5. Pardon for my stupidity :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
DownloadProgress n;
```

to

```
DownloadProgress* n(new DownloadProgress(this));
```

and

```
connect(red, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(updateDownloadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
```

to connect to

```
connect(red, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), n, SLOT(updateDownloadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
```

Comment: well i tried your solution before i asked this question, it didn't worked. (no matching function for call to 'Options::connect(QNetworkReply*&, const char [33], DownloadProgress&, const char [40])'
     connect(red, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), n, SLOT(updateDownloadProgress(qint64, qint64)))

Comment: @user3343366:It seems you are not supplying a pointer for DownloadProgress to connect. You need to create it on the heap otherwise it will be gone too early as this will run asynchronously.